A Limit Involving the Weierstrass $\wp$ and $\zeta$ Functions
I am learning Costa's minimal surface these days, and I try to analyze the asymptotic behavior of its two catenoidal ends. To be specific, I come across the problem of determining the following limit (assuming $u\in\mathbb{R}$):
$$\lim_{u\to1/2}\frac{-\log\left(-\frac{\pi}{4\wp(1/2)}\zeta(u-1/2)\right)}{\log\left(1-\frac{2\wp(1/2)}{\wp(u)+\wp(1/2)}\right)}.$$
Here the corresponding lattice is the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and the two Weierstrass elliptic functions are defined as follows:
\begin{gather*}
\wp(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{\omega\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\setminus\{0\}}\left(\frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2}-\frac{1}{\omega^2}\right),\\
\zeta(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{\omega\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\setminus\{0\}}\left(\frac{1}{z-\omega}+\frac{1}{\omega}+\frac{z}{\omega^2}\right).
\end{gather*}
p.s. I have tried numerical methods with Mathematica, and it gave 0.5 as the output. But I am not sure about this. Can anyone help me figure it out? Thanks in advance.

Update: With the addition formula
$$\wp(z+1/2)=\wp(1/2)+\frac{2[\wp(1/2)]^2}{\wp(z)-\wp(1/2)}$$
I simplify the denominator, and now the limit becomes
$$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{-\log\left(-\frac{\pi\zeta(u)}{4\wp(1/2)}\right)}{\log\left(\frac{\wp(1/2)}{\wp(u)}\right)}.$$

From the definition of $\wp$ and $\zeta$, we have the following asymptotics:
$$
\wp(z)={1\over z^2}+O(1),\quad\zeta(z)=\frac1z+O(1).\quad (z\to0)
$$
Hence, when $u\to0$, we have
$$
-\log\left(-{\pi\zeta(u)\over4\wp(1/2)}\right)=-\log u^{-1}+O(1)\tag1
$$
and
$$
\log{\wp(1/2)\over\wp(u)}=\log u^2+O(1).\tag2
$$
Dividing (1) by (2) gives the desired result.
